# Allow all users with a certain role to set Groups Audience to any Organic Group

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

I am using Drupal 7.
What I am trying to achieve is the following:
I have several users with a particular role say "A". And I have several content types set as "Group content"
When a user with role "A" creates content I would like the user to be able to set the Groups Audience field to any of the existing Organic Groups.

Is it possible to achieve without adding those users as Administrators to all existing Organic Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the above requirement using OG Role Override module.
From Global Permissions for role "A" we would set:
"Act as role 'member' in OG Node Group Main Page groups"

Hope this helps!